# Separate sublist in other sublists

Tags: python-3.x

I want to separate every sublist of a list (alumnos) in other two lists (rojo and azul), considering if the name is in the next sublist and then I want to to have another two lists with the respective values. I am relativiely new with python and my best try is below, but it's not functioning. If somebody can give me a hand, I'll appreciate so much.

```
alumnos = [['Charlie', 'Fran', 'Lucas', 'Mario', 'Juan'], ['Mario', 'Juan'], ['Mario']]
values = [[3, 2.5, 2.8, 1, 1.2], [2, 2.5], [2.8]]
azul = []
rojo = []
azul_va = []
rojo_va = []
cont = 0
while cont<3:
    for l in alumnos[cont]:
        if l in alumnos[cont+1]:
            rojo.append(l)
        else:
            azul.append(l)
    cont += 1
print(f'{alumnos}')
print(rojo)
print(azul)
```

error: list index out of range.

output(expected): 
rojo_va = [[1, 1.2], [2]]
azul_va = [[3, 2.5, 2.8], [2.5], [2.8]]

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: whatfor is `values` ? its not used anywhere

Comment: while cont<3 ... alumnos[cont+1] will indeed get out of range, the last time

Comment: The expected output is: rojo=[[Mario, Juan], [Mario]], azul = [[Charlie, Fran, Lucas], [Juan]], and the related values; Rojo_va=[[1, 1.2], [2]] and Azul_va=[[3, 2.5, 2.8],[2.5]]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are the `values` not used anywhere? If you are just expecting the common and uncommon values between the successive lists then the below code should work.

```
alumnos = [['Charlie', 'Fran', 'Lucas', 'Mario', 'Juan'], ['Mario', 'Juan'], ['Mario']]
values = [[3, 2.5, 2.8, 1, 1.2], [2, 2.5], [2.8]]
azul = []
rojo = []

alumons_values = []
for l, r in zip(alumnos, values):
    n = []
    for l1, r1 in zip(l, r):
        n.append((l1, r1))
    alumons_values.append(n)

get_first = lambda t : list(map(lambda x : x[0], t))
get_second = lambda t : list(map(lambda x : x[1], t))

for l1, l2 in zip(alumons_values, alumons_values[1:]):
    lm1 = get_first(l1)
    lm2 = get_first(l2)
    r = set(lm1) & set(lm2)
    a = set(lm1) - set(lm2)
    ri = [lm1.index(v) for v in lm1 if v in r]
    ai = [lm1.index(v) for v in lm1 if v in a]
    source = get_second(l1)
    rojo.append([source[i] for i in ri])
    azul.append([source[i] for i in ai])

print('Azul :', azul)
print('Rojo :', rojo)
```

Output:

```
Azul : [[3, 2.5, 2.8], [2.5]]
Rojo : [[1, 1.2], [2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the expected output. The expected output is: rojo=[[Mario, Juan], [Mario]], azul = [[Charlie, Fran, Lucas], [Juan]], and the related values; Rojo_va=[[1, 1.2], [2]] and Azul_va=[[3, 2.5, 2.8],[2.5]]. @Praveenkumar

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. And add the expected output in your question. Check my latest edit.